# Facebook canvas app continuosly loading within the iOS Facebook app

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've just deployed https://apps.facebook.com/caci_christmas_gifts/ and I'm having trouble when accessing it on the facebook iOS app.

Direct link to the app is at https://fb.commonroom.co.nz/caci_advent_2014/tree.php? and this continuously loads with a spinning icon at the top.

[image: facebookapp]

Loading the app through Safari / on desktop, it works fine.

Has anyone struck this behaviour before? / Any tips for debugging sites from within Facebook's iOS app?

Cheers

Comment: Canvas apps are not meant to work on IOS

Comment: I have the same problem. Therefore, I think that the canvas apps implementation intended to be used from the desktop not mobile.